# Running Python from Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

In Sublime, we have an easy and convent way to run Python or almost any language for that matter using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>)

Where the code will run in a small window below the source code and can easily be closed with the escape key when no longer needed.

Is there a way to replicate this functionally with Github's atom editor?

Comment: I added the `python` tag since this looks to me like a python-specific IDE question, feel free to revert it.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The *script* package does exactly what you're looking for: https://atom.io/packages/script

The package's documentation also contains the key mappings, which you can easily customize.

Comment: However script has poor support for Python 3.

Comment: It also has poor support for `input`.

Comment: I like it.  Thanks.  I was using pyenv and local virtenv.  I tried to run the current python file with Packages->script->Run Script.  It failed and popped up a dialog. I copied the `which python` from terminal in the local virtenv and away it ran.

Answer (score 17):

Download and Install package here: https://atom.io/packages/script

To execute the python command in atom use the below shortcuts:

For Windows/Linux, it's SHIFT + Ctrl + B OR  Ctrl + SHIFT + B

If you're on Mac, press ⌘ + I

Comment: On Mac, when press `⌘ + I`, it says **Unable to run python.  Did you start Atom from the command line?**

Answer (score 3):

To run the python file on mac.

1. Open the preferences in atom ide. To open the preferences press 'command + . '
   ( ⌘ + , )
2. Click on the install in the preferences to install packages.
3. Search for package "script" and click on install
4. Now open the python file(with .py extension ) you want to run and press 'control + r ' (^ + r)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by:

-- Install Atom

-- Install Python on your system. Atom requires the latest version of Python (currently 3.8.5). Note that Anaconda sometimes may not have this version, and depending on how you installed it, it may not have been added to the PATH. Install Python via https://www.python.org/ and make sure to check the option of "Add to PATH"

-- Install "[scripts](https://atom.io/packages/script)" on Atom via "Install packages"

-- Install any other autocomplete package like Kite on Atom if you want that feature.

-- Run it

I tried the normal way (I had Python installed via Anaconda) but Atom did not detect it & gave me an error when I tried to run Python. This is the way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. Install Python
2. Install Atom
3. Install and configure Atom package for Python
4. Install and configure Python Linter
5. Install Script Package in Atom
6. Download and install Syntax Highlighter for Python
7. Install Version control package Run Python file

More details for each step Click [Here](https://ssiddique.info/how-to-use-atom-for-python.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called "platformio-ide-terminal" that allows you to run Atom code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>". That's the only package you need (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to install the script package in Atom.

```
apm install script
```