# Compile C programs in GitHub Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I just got the new GitHub text editor. However, it doesn't seem to have a compile feature like Sublime Text has. `CTRL+B` does nothing for me. Do I have to enable it using a plugin or is this feature not available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [run python from atom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585500/run-python-from-atom)

Comment: I can second vindvaki's answer. Just install the package `script`: `cmd-i` (OS X) or `shift-ctrl-b` (Linux/Windows) to run.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no such functionality shipped with atom.

There are, however packages such as the [build package](https://atom.io/packages/build), which should work as long as you have a build system configured (or a custom build command); there is also a package called [script](https://atom.io/packages/script), which supports something along those lines for C if you are on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [script](https://atom.io/packages/script) package and simply use Ctrl+I instead of Ctrl+B.