# How to configure Atom to run Python3 scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, atom-editor

In my terminal, I type `$ which python3`, outputting

```
/opt/local/bin/python3
```

I would like to configure Atom to run Python3 scripts. In my Atom Config, I have

```
runner:
python: "/opt/local/bin/python3"
```

However, if I run the following script in some script named `filename.py`,

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

I get the following output:

```
2.7.11 (default, Feb 18 2016, 22:00:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)]
```

How exactly does one set up the PATH for Python3.x scripts to run correctly? Is there a different package I could use?

Comment: Nahuel and Terry are correct. However if you use something like 'script' and want to permanently set python3 as default interpreter in Atom use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42033743/1955372

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Go to the Atom's menu bar -> Packages -> Script -> Configure Script
(Or, you can use the shortcut Shift+Ctrl+Alt+O)

Then type `python3` to the Command space.
Hopefully, it will work.

Comment: It works fine. But when I relaunch Atom, I've to perform the same steps again. Is there any way to persist this configuration?

Comment: @AnshulGarg one of the best ways to be consistent with the specific file you want is to add the shebang at the top of the file: `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` this way you can specify which python interpreter you want to use on a per file basis.

Comment: @AnshulGarg is absolutely correct, this is the only way to maintain your sanity longer if you are working with one of the popular IDEs or package managers. I will not name names, but you know who you are.

Answer (score 12):

i am using "script" package (3.18.1 by rgbkrk) to run code inside atom and this is how i fixed it

1. open package settings -> view code
2. open lib -> grammars -> python.coffee
3. change from python to python3 in those two places 'Selection Based' and 'File Based'

Answer (score 6):

Install atom-runner in your Atom going into your settings of Atom and then inside Package and search for atom-runner and install it.
[image]

Now click on settings tab  for atom-runner as shown above on picture.
Then click on View Code as shown in below picture.
[image]

Then go to lib folder and open atom-runner.coffee and replace the following section of code:

```
defaultScopeMap:
coffee: 'coffee'
js: 'node'
ruby: 'ruby'
python: 'python3'
go: 'go run'
shell: 'bash'
powershell: 'powershell -noninteractive -noprofile -c -'
```

Make sure that for python keyword value is python3, by default it is python. Refer to the pic below:
[image]

Other way is to find the location of python3 using command

```
which python3
```

for me output is :

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

and add as a shebang in your every python file. For example:-

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import sys
print("Version ",sys.version)
```

Only catch is that you have to write this in each file.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Mac OS X, use the directory on the terminal to open the file.

Select the file python3, right click and select "get info". Select the directory from "Where:" and past it in Atom.

As Terry told you:

> Then type python3 to the Command space.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Atom package [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run) to launch python code from Atom, the python version can be configured in the package settings. By default atom-python-run uses the syntax `python {file}`. If the python command on your system is not yet pointing to python3, just replace the setting and write `python3 {file}`.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using **atom-python-run** package to run Python directly from Atom. If Python2 is the default version of Python in your system, then Atom will try to run your Python code with Python2 interpreter. All you have to do is to change some settings in **atom-python-run** package to tell it that we want to use Python3. The process is simple. Go to **settings**>>**Packages**, click the settings button on **atom-python-run** package and in the fields of F5 and F6 command, **exchange python with python3**. That's it. Now you can run your Python3 script by pressing F5 or F6 button.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Atom on Mac OS and have script 3.18.1 and atom-python-run 0.9.7 packages installed, the following steps will help you out.

Script-> Configure Script

[image]

Then type in Python3 in the command field in the options dialog.

[image]

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For mac user:
if you want to use Python3 by default, you can open Atom Settings, Atom→Preferences→Open Config Folder, and open.atom/packages/script/lib/grammars/python.coffee, Changing python to python3 under 'Selection Based' and 'File Based', saving it.

Comment: On Mac with Apple silicon and Atom 1.58.0 x64, there was no python.coffee file but there was python.js file in the same folder. Changed    command: "python"     to     command:  "python3"     inside "Selection Based" and "File Based" context. Restarted Atom and it started picking python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Im using Linux/Ubuntu so in other Linux distro and Mac this method will work.

First you need go to **package settings** and find `Script` and click its `Settings`.

[image: Image 1]

in next step click on `view code`.

[image: Image 2]

With this, you will get access to all the main source files of the package. follow the path below to reach the `python.js` file.

```
> lib > grammars > python.js
```

[image: Image 3]

Now you need to change the highlighted parts to the following value, you just need to change the `python` to `python3` :

```
export const Python = {
  "Selection Based": {
    command: "python3",
    args(context) {
      setEncoding()
      const code = context.getCode()
      const tmpFile = GrammarUtils.createTempFileWithCode(code)
      return ["-u", tmpFile]
    },
  },

  "File Based": {
    command: "python3",
    args({ filepath }) {
      setEncoding()
      return ["-u", filepath]
    },
  },
}
```

Save the file and close it and return to your program and run your program using **Run Script** or **Ctrl + shift + b** .

You will get the following result

[image: Image 4]

Everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your command in the Configure Run Options and save it. Then use 'Run with Profile' to use the command to execute your script. This worked for me.
[image]

Comment: Putting the full path the the python executable here worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have Atom v1.57.0 application installed in Ubuntu 20.04 and the atom package called [script](https://atom.io/packages/script) is installed to execute python3 scripts.

To allow Atom configuration to run python3 script persistently, I installed the `python-is-python3` package by running the terminal command `sudo apt install python-is-python3`. These links [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296790/python-is-python3-package-in-ubuntu-20-04-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-actually) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/1272899/541417) explain what it is. So simply pressing `Ctrl+Shift+B` or `Run Script` will run the python3 scripts persistently by default and without error messages.

If you do not want `python` to be replace `python3` at the system-wide level, you can uninstalled `python-is-python3`, i.e. run terminal command  `sudo apt remove python-is-python3`. Then in Atom, pressed `Ctrl+Shift+P`, typed `script` and selected `Script: Run Options`. For `Command`, you can key in the path `/usr/bin/python3.8` or `/usr/bin/python3` to define using `python3.8` or `python3` to execute your  python script. Thereafter, you have to click on `Save as profile`, give it a profile name and then selected that profile name to execute your python script.  See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjEuROpsvp4) that was created by Corey-Schafer from 18.21mins. It shows you what to do. So finally, instead of using  `Ctrl+Shift+B` or `Run Script` to execute your script, you now have to use  `Alt+Ctrl+Shift+B` or `Run With Profile` to execute the script. More tedious but this approach allows finer control. For folks who want to use Atom to run different version-types of Python scripts.