# Atom.io python 3 on Mac, cant get it to work :(

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

Beginner here.
Downloaded python3 , downloaded atom.
tried to follow some guide to get it going but to no avail. If I Use 
"which python3"

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

Where can I enter this in atom to get it to use python3 ?

This is how my config looks like :

```
"*":
  "atom-python-run":
    f5Command: "python3 {file}"
  "autocomplete-python":
    useKite: false
  core:
    packagesWithKeymapsDisabled: []
    telemetryConsent: "no"
    themes: [
      "one-dark-ui"
      "predawn-syntax"
    ]
  editor:
    fontFamily: "Source Code Pro"
    fontSize: 20
    tabLength: 4
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "dbab5103-2f7f-43f3-8751-feba53c74d95"
    runner:
        scopes:
            python: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3"
```

Comment: Your question is moot. Could you post the link to the stated guide?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546627/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts

Answer (score 0):

The [`atom-runner` documentation](https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner#configuring) specifically says to put the `runner` key underneath `"*"`. You have it underneath `"*".editor` and it should be on the same indentation level as the other package settings, like `atom-python-run`.