# Python- fail to execute script using Atom

Tags: python, tkinter, atom-editor

I'm using Ubuntu 16.0.4, and just installed Atom, to edit and wishfully exec python script ( using run package and Hydrogen). Python is installed and working OK, but when trying to using `tkinter` i'm getting an error message :

```
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

as said - python is working fine is other IDE's

when checking path - it shows only python2.7's path

any idea ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done any research before asking. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: @BryanOakley - quite did. any lead how to change it to run python3?

Comment: [How to configure Atom to run Python3 scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35546627/7432)

Answer (score 0):

Run Atom from a directory that returns python3 when typing 'which python'.
For example, if in directory test1, type `which python`. If that returns something like usr/bin/python3 then running Atom from the test1 directory will default to python3.