# ImportError: No module named xxx, no matter what package that is

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, atom-editor

So I have Python 3.6.5 installed on my MacOS.

```
$ python3 --version
  Python 3.6.5
```

and I have some packages installed through pip3, that I need for the development.

And it turns out that when I import these packages the error message will show up.

```
import  xxxxxx
   ImportError: No module named XXXXXX
```

I've tried

`brew reinstall python`

`brew reinstall python3`

the problem remains.

and I thought the package name should all be lower case when import them, so I did, and it didn't work neither.

What should I check next to find out what caused the error

Comment: please run `import sys; print(sys.path)` and paste the output here

Comment: Are you sure you provided output for `python3`, not `python` ?

Comment: I am sorry, I was running the scripts on Atom.

Comment: '/Users/John/Documents', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages'

Comment: Ok, I think I know what cause the problem, When I run the code on Terminal the result indicated the output is python3, and when I run it on Atom it was using the system build-in python (which is the older version). What should I do about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved. If you happened using Atom editor you will find this link helpful

[How to configure Atom to run Python3 scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546627/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Try using either of these

- pip install XXXXXX - if runtime is python2
- pip3 install XXXXXX - if runtime is python3

Comment: Oh, hey thanks for the response. I have the packages installed through `pip3 install xxxx`, I have even tried reinstall these packages. Another thing that I want to mention is that I use `pip3 list` and all packages that I need were showed up on the list

Comment: It looks like brew only installed python3 with pip3, not pip, when I use pip, it showed 'pip command not found' somehow

Comment: Can you try installing pip from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ as based on the output of sys.path python3 is nowhere mentioned

Comment: Ok, I did 'sudo easy_install pip' to install the pip, but it seems like we are heading to the wrong direction