# problem with Run python3 code in Atom on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, atom-editor, ubuntu-18.04

script i am using this package on atom.

getting this error

```
[Command: python3 -u '/home/aditya/Documents/python/py4e book solved problems/not done py4e 5.10ex q1 loop.py']
```

after making change  to. `[/home/aditya/.atom/packages/script/lib/grammars]` i had changed python to python3

```
exports.Python =
  'Selection Based':
    command: 'python3'
    args: (context) -> ['-u', '-c', context.getCode()]

  'File Based':
    command: 'python3'
    args: ({filepath}) -> ['-u', filepath]
```

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly addition to that add some context to your question like what have you tried? what error you getting? what you trying to achieve? what is expected etc..

Comment: @Aditya singh I don't know if I understood your question correctly. But I presume you aren't able to run your python scripts through atom on ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, iam not able to run python3 in atom

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546627/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** if you just want to run python3 through atom:
Open the atom-python-run package settings (atom Settings >> packages >> find atom-python-run >> settings)

In `F5` command section, change the default to `python3 {file}`. It should look something like this.

**EDIT:** Make sure that `F5` doesn't interfere with another command from another package. Or else you can use `F6` as well.
[image]

Restart, atom. You should be good to go!

If you aren't able to run python scripts through atom. Then here's the package you can install.

[atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run)

In short:

1. You need python installed on your computer and you need to add it to your `PATH`
2. Restart atom
3. To run your (.py) file, hit `F5` or `F6`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want too run python3

Comment: That package does exactly that. You just need to have python 3  installed to your machine

Comment: Yes i have.iam using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: No it auto run with python2

Comment: That wouldn't happen. The package just allows you to run the script through atom. Check the version with ```python -v```. I believe you just have a different version. The package does no auto run.

Comment: Ubuntu comes with both py2&3 i want to run my code with python3

Comment: @Aditya singh -- modified answer. Let me know if it worked ;)

Comment: @Adityasingh glad it worked. Be sure to read the edit I just made (upvote if it works for you as well)

Answer (score 0):

Try running "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python".

Anyway you can change the default to python3 {file} on settings atom python    run from.