# Keep getting syntax error on print function?

Tags: python, atom-editor

On Atom, I am trying to run a program and get a syntax error for this line I typed: print(f"Let's talk about {my_name}.")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question and use the "{}" button to format the code as such, and and the text of the syntax error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

f string intepolation does not work in python 2.

The same thing works just fine in python3. In python3 I get my_name is not defined error for that.

Could you check that atom actually runs python3, at least 3.6.

To set up atom to use python3 please see this: [How to configure Atom to run Python3 scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546627/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts)