# I'm coding a simple print statement. However i get a syntax error in atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

Please note this code is directly from a python book (2nd edition python crash course by eric mathes). When I run the code, it does compile though the regular python idle 3.7.5. However when I try to compile the code through the atom editor, it does not compile.

I've installed many python packages for atom editor, including python snippits, python tools, run-python-simply. But this still doesn't seem to compile.

```
first_name = "Adam"
last_name = "Scott"
full_name = f"{first_name}{last_name}"
print(full_name)

File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/full_name.py", line 3
    full_name = f"{first_name}{last_name}"
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55360117/2613005
Maybe atom is using python2 for compilation.

Comment: It's probably because you are using an older python version which doesn't support fstrings.

Comment: Are you sure Atom is trying to run this in Python 3.7? Do you have other versions of Python installed? Note: the interpreter is failing, not the compilation

Comment: Try to print version `import sys` , `print(sys.version)`. it must be printing `3.6` or later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [f-strings giving SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401632/f-strings-giving-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 2):

You can use f-string only after **Python 3.6** (including) so better to check the version or you can use older method `format()` to achieve the same output.

```
first_name = "Adam"
last_name = "Scott"
full_name = "{0} {1}".format(first_name, last_name)
print(full_name)

Adam Scott
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm working through the same book. once in the correct directory for the script, type: python3 full_name.py

I had the same issue as you from typing just "python"

You prolly solved it long ago.  Python 2.7 was running instead of python 3.x

-Andy