# Python: Traceback XML-file error? and ASCII and 'ascii' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, character-encoding

My first post :o) Also my first python steps. I want to fetch data from an xml api and searched for some youtube videos. I found this one: https://youtu.be/jeZp5NE9lII?t=685 (XML part)

I "copied" the code from the video (where the python script runs) to found out if I can fetch informations from an XML API or if I need to add something to my ATOM or Python. Here the code:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries'

response = requests.get(url)
country_data = response.text

countries = ET.fromstring(country_data)

namespaces = {'wb': 'http://www.worldbank.org'}

for country in countries.findall('wb:country', namespaces):
    name = country.find('wb:name', namespaces).text
    code = country.find('wb:iso2Code', namespaces).text

print('country: {} {}'.format(name, code))
```

Had some errors. So I installed on my mac:

1. `sudo easy_install pip`
2. `python -m pip install requests`

Now I have the following error:

````
  File "/var/folders/2k/ynjbnhl17pg6_wtr20l149xh0000gn/T/atom_script_tempfiles/3a3bf940-16b6-11eb-8d53-6b13b4204efb", line 30, in <module>
    countries = ET.fromstring(country_data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1311, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1657, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode```

What I did wrong?
````

Comment: Do you have a really, really good reason to be writing in Python 2.7? As a beginner you should not be investing time in learning it. One of the major changes in Python 3 is that its Unicode strings do away with many mystifying encoding and decoding challenges.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. No there is no reason why I use Python 2.7. Actually I had Python 3.9 installed. According to my research, Atom goes to the standard version of Mac OS = Python 2.7, so I have Python 2 and 3 on the Mac co-exist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546627/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts. So I had to set the right Python Version in Atom: 

After that the error message changed that I did not install Requests ;)

Comment: That is an expected message. Installing a module in one Python environment does net make it available in another. The code could well be different. So after changing to Python 3, go to your Python 2 environment, and do `pip list` to find out what installs you need to do in Python 3 to replicate what you have in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you print the first 50 characters of `response.text`, you get this:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wb:cou
```

The strange looking characters at the beginning are a Byte Order Mark, and their presence suggests that requests hasn't decoded the file correctly.  Instead of using `response.text`, use `response.content` to pass the raw bytes to elementtree:

```
 country_data = response.content
```

Resulting in this output

```
country: China CN
```

Comment: You may find it easier to work with different encodings if you use Python 3 rather than Python 2.