# how to import libraries in python3 (using mac)?

Tags: python

```py
import  urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen("http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt")

for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip)
```

Output for the above code when executed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/veerrajupallapothu/Desktop/py4e/ex_10/url.py", line 1, in <module>
    import  urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
ImportError: No module named request
```

Comment: Hi @Veera, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question so that it's clear what your problem is. You could start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How about: from urllib import request, parse, error

Answer (score 0):

I am a macOS user my self and when I ran python and then run the code I encountered the same error as you. But when I ran it using the command `python3` it worked successfully.

By default macOS uses python 2.7 therefore to run it using python3 which running the program using terminal use

`python3 filename.py` instead of `python filename.py` it should work now :)

Comment: I'm running the code in atom text editor and I encountered the issue. I want to use atom instead of terminal to run the code. Please run the code in atom and let me know the result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546627/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts

Comment: Hi @Rajat Shenoi, There is an error in the line of code if I use strip() the code executes perfectly without having any issues. either it is python2 or pyhton3 doesn't matter and didn't change the file name. Thanks for your help anyways.