# Opencv-python not importing to Atom

Tags: python

I have just started using Atom, on Mac, and need to use "opencv-python".
I install it in the terminal using`pip3 install opencv-python` and it installs. I confirm this by using `pip3 list` and it is definitely there. Then, in the Atom IDE I run `import cv2` and it returns `ImportError: No module named cv2`.
I have tried uninstalling and installing it again, but it did nothing.
Any solves?

Comment: Are you sure Atom is using the Python 3 interpreter and not the default Python 2 one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Atom to run Python3 scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35546627/6045800)

Comment: looks good but I need to access /home/.atom/packages/script/lib/python.coffee and I don't know how to access it.