# How to switch to a different python version in Atom?

Tags: python, interpreter, atom-editor

I need to use Python 3.5 instead of 2.7. But I cannot find any 'run options' or 'interpreter configurations' in Atom. My current interpreter is Python 2.7 in `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python'`. I have installed 3.5 which is in `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python'`.
Besides, I am using Mac OSX.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious, what package are you using that would require a Python interpreter?

Comment: What if you add the `PATH` of the desired Python version to Configure / Run / Options?

Comment: did you installed atom-runner and configured config.cson  file ?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32066058/2027457 check this solution.

Comment: I tried this, but my os is OSX, and after I reinstalled python and atom, the path still point to 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Finally, find the solution. In folder of '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/', python is named as python3.5. So all I need is deleting '3.5' and use 'python' along.