# How can I change default Python version on the cmd in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, path

I have python **v2.7** and **3.6** on Windows 10. I installed 3.6 later and also chose the option **"Add to PATH"**. In the command line, when I type `python`, I get v3.6. I already tried to set PATH in **View Advanced System Settings**, but it doesn't work and python 3.6 is also no where to be found there. So when I want to set v2.7 as default (in order to run python script in the Atom Editor or the cmd), I have to reinstall v2.7 and ticked the **"Add to PATH"** option.

How can I set my new default python version to use for example in a text editor or cmd... without having to reinstall it?

Comment: Have you tried removing Python2.7 from the PATH variable? (search for `edit enviroment variables` in start)

Comment: I already did that. The problem is Python doesn't need to be in the PATH variable in order to run.

Comment: From my knowledge(Could be wrong) the cmd, whenever you run something, this is in no particular order: checks the local directory, then the Win32 folder, then the PATH variables(Where Python is). In Edit Enviroment variables, did you click edit on the PATH variable and remove Python2.7?

Comment: @CoolqB, cmd.exe does a custom search that does not check system directories before the `PATH` directories and also tries appending the extensions in `PATHEXT`. Stating with Vista, it includes the working directory only if `NeedCurrentDirectoryForExePath(name)` is true, which depends on the value of the environment variable `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath`.

Comment: I always recommend to use the python launcher in the Windows command-line `py -2 script.py`, `py -3 script.py` or the specific version `py -3.6 script.py` instead of fiddling with the PATH. As for the Atom problem, there are some other threads on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36710442/6220679 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42033743/6220679 (try to set it to "py -2")

Comment: @HuyTran, when you change `PATH` in the control panel dialog, it updates Explorer and other top-level windows are notified of the change, but cmd.exe is a console application that doesn't own a top-level window (the console is conhost.exe), so it doesn't get updated. You have to start a new instance of cmd from Explorer to see the updated environment.

Comment: I recommend removing Python from your persisted user and system `PATH` values. Use virtual environments and create shortcuts to their activate.bat scripts. Change the shortcut's command line in the properties to `cmd /k "path\to\activate.bat"`.

Answer (score 7):

For running Python 3 on your computer from the Command Prompt: enter `py -3.6 myfile.py`

For running Python 2.7: `py -2.7 myfile.py`

This also works if you have Python 3.4 and Python 3.6 installed, just change the argument.

Answer (score -3):

Easy solution.
My last installation was python 3.6 (folder name Python36-32).
I just changed folder name to something like Python36-32- and now python 2.7 running.