# Specify Python3 to Atom on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, ide, atom-editor

In advance, sorry if this is question ought be on SuperUser or another site

The python3 shebang doesn't seem to work on win10. (I cant check right now, but I believe the analogous approach worked on MacOS for me last night). Consider the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("hello world")
```

Leads to the error `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`. This makes sense because I only have a python3 distro on my machine (which can only be called like `python3`). However, Atom seems to be ignoring the shebang altogether. FYI, I'm running the script with the popular "script" atom package.

I've tried the permutation, `#!/usr/bin python3`, but this doesn't work either.

I've tried permutations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still interested in how shebangs work within the Atom environment, but as far as getting python3 up and running, you dont need a shebang. You can simply change a config file (python.coffee) from within Atom, then relaunch. See Daniel Chamorro's excellent answer here: [How to setup Atom's script to run Python 3.x scripts? May the combination with Windows 7 Pro x64 be the issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006771/how-to-setup-atoms-script-to-run-python-3-x-scripts-may-the-combination-with-w/42033743#42033743)