# Atom prioritizes Python 2.7 over Python 3.7 on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, atom-editor

I have just installed Python 3.7 together with Atom on my Mac running High Sierra because I want to start learning the language.

To setup Python correctly, I have also installed the *Xcode commands*, *homebrew*, *virtualenv*, *pip* and *git* as well as some useful packages in Atom such as *linter-flake8*, *python-autopep8*, *script*, etc.

I know that macOS High Sierra is shipped with a pre installed version of Python (2.7.10).

Now, when I run
`import sys // print("Version ",sys.version)` in Atom through *script* to test which version of Python it uses, it outputs Python 2.7.10 and NOT Python 3.7.0 (the version I want).

Testing Atom further, I noticed that the only two packages (linter-flake8 and python-autopep8) where I had to manually install packages through pip in my terminal seem not to be working.

Furthermore, typing `apm --version` in my terminal outputs:

```
apm  1.19.0
npm  3.10.10
node 6.9.5 x64
atom 1.29.0
python 2.7.10
git 2.18.0
```

Notice here, again, that the Atom Package Manager (`apm`) displays Python 2.7.10 and NOT Python 3.7.0.

My conclusion is that Atom and the Atom Package Manager seem to prioritize Python 2.7.10 over Python 3.7.0 (or maybe not even recognize Python 3.7?).

Therefore my question: How can I make Atom and `apm` prioritize/recognize Python 3.7?

I have tried a lot of things without success but maybe there is still hope for me to start learning Python (3.7) on my machine ;).

Information that may be relevant:

- Operating system: macOS 10.13.6
- Atom version: 1.29.0
- Python 3.7 path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
- PATH variable: PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"

---

**Edit:**
I managed to change *script* and now it runs Python 3.7 thanks to the linked answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006771/how-to-setup-atoms-script-to-run-python-3-x-scripts-may-the-combination-with-w/42033743#42033743).

However, I want Atom and especially the Atom Package Manager (`apm`) to prioritize Python 3.7 over 2.7. This is still an issue.

Thanks for the answer though, it goes in the right direction :).

Comment: this is a duplicate question.
Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546627/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts

Comment: you should create a virtual environment for each version of python you plan on running.

Comment: As the linked answer mentions, you can set this in the package settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Atom to run Python3 scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546627/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts)