# PlatformIO conflicts with Python 2 on Atom

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.6, linux-mint, platformio

If I want to run Python inside ATOM, I have to always disable PlatformIO and restart ATOM again, so it works fine.  I managed to avoid that pain by pointing my installed Python packages to run Python 3, instead of the standard Python (Python 2), But I really wish I could understand what's happening so I could use any of the versions freely, as I need. Any light on the subject?

My system Is Linux(mint 19)
Thanks!!!

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: "Error,no module x,y or z(etc)" - python cant find any of my modules installed(pygame,pyfirmata,etc)when I run  under atom,but it only occurs If I run with python 2(2.7) and platformIO enabled

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your default Python is 2.7, but everything is installed against Python 3, and Atom always uses Python 2. You can fix this by changing the default Python that is used by Atom.

For one off uses, try [How to configure Atom to run Python3 scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546627/how-to-configure-atom-to-run-python3-scripts) and for permanently changing the version of Python for Atom, have a look at [How to setup Atom's script to run Python 3.x scripts? May the combination with Windows 7 Pro x64 be the issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006771/how-to-setup-atoms-script-to-run-python-3-x-scripts-may-the-combination-with-w/42033743#42033743) (despite Windows 7 Pro in the title, the solution applies to Atom in general).

Comment: thanks for the answer,thats what I'm doing already...just using python 3 on atom...But I would be glad if I could use 2.7 too(without disabling plataformIO)

Comment: Why not use vscode for platformio and leave atom for Python?