# How do I get Atom to run Python3 in the terminal platformio-ide-terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

On my terminal, `$ which python` (~ is my home directory) gives

```
~/anaconda3/bin/python
```

However, running the same command when opening Atom on my terminal (with `$ atom .`) yields

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

My `python3` is different to my default `python` now, but I do have Anaconda's python3 working well on my Terminal.

I have already tried various things:

- changing `python` to `python3` in the two instances in `~/.atom/packages/script/lib/grammars/python.coffee` as was laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006771/how-to-setup-atoms-script-to-run-python-3-x-scripts-may-the-combination-with-w/42033743#42033743)
- installing `atom-runner` and changing `python` to `python3` as was shown [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/basic_search.html)
- Changed the shebang in my script to `#!~/anaconda3/bin/python` (note: the `~` is not what I literally have on my script)
- Note 1: I did not have to do the second point with Python 2
- Note 2: In the same link as above, I did try out `atom-python-run` and it worked, but I would like to not use hot keys to run Python on the terminal on Atom, I'd rather manually type in `python [script]`.

If it's relevant, I just upgraded to Mojave (Mac OSX 10.14.6) and Python 3 (3.7.4). Of course, I restarted Atom each time I made the changes as well.

My end goal is to run `python [script]` on the terminal in Atom (with `platformio-ide-terminal`) where it executes from `~/anaconda3/bin/python`. Finally, if I do do `~/anaconda3/bin/python [script]`, it does work, but I would like a more practical solution.

I forgot to add this before, but when I do try running a script, I get import errors, for example, `ImportError: No module named astropy.io`, even though I definitely have AstroPy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate your virtual environment from the command line. Then run Atom and open your python file. Now hit the F5 or F6 key and your code should run using python 3.x. Where 3.x is however you set up your virtual environment.

To run Python from the terminal in atom, open the terminal and type

> python3 script_file

If your virtual environment was set up for python 3.7, then run

> python3.7 script_file

To determine what versions you have type which python3 or which phython3,7 or any other version you may have installed.