# Need to find /home/.atom/packages/script/lib/python.coffee in Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

Pretty self-explanatory, need to get to **/home/.atom/packages/script/lib/python.coffee** file to edit but have no idea.
Any solves?

Comment: You almost certainly mean `/home/<youruser>/.atom/packages...`, right?

Comment: Found this file path in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42033743/18383718, just can't figure out how to get there

Comment: Have you tried the path @TimRoberts mentioned?

Comment: Where should I enter this?

Comment: Note: Working on Mac

Comment: The Mac doesn't use `/home`, it has  `/Users`.   This would be in `/Users/<youruser>/.atom/packages...`.  If you're in a terminal, you can use `~/.atom/packages...`.  The lesson is that the `.atom` folder should be in the root of your home directory.