# Run Code In Atom Code Editor

Tags: python, windows, atom-editor

I have read numerous articles about running code in the Atom code editor, however, I cannot seem to understand how this can be done. Could anyone explain it in simpler terms?

I want to run my Python code in it and I have downloaded the 'python-tools-0.6.5' and 'atom-script-2.29.0' files from the Atom website and I just need to know how to get them working.

Comment: What OS you are using on your computer?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1, sorry - forgot to mention that.

Comment: Have you ever checkout this: https://atom.io/packages/atom-runner

Comment: I am just not sure on how to install the package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python from Atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585500/running-python-from-atom)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

From Atom > Preferences > Install:

Search for **atom-runner** package and install it.

After you have installed the package atom-runner on Atom;

Create a new document and copy&paste your code to new document and save the document with **.py** extension. For example **myfile.py**

Last step execute the atom-runner using this shortcut:

> Hit Ctrl+R (Alt+R on Win/Linux) to launch the runner for the active
>   window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I installed it, however the following error appears: Unable to find command: python
Are you sure PATH is configured correctly?

Comment: @BG_Programmer This is the answer for your new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32609129/2104879

Comment: I have made the Python variable, how would I change the path in Atom?

Comment: @BG_Programmer You should be missing something if you currently assigned the Environment Variable.

Comment: I assigned the following path: C:\Users\BG_Programmer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.5

Comment: It seems not correct. It should look like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/2104879

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like a package that supports user input too, consider [script-runner](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner). It's very similar but uses a proper terminal for executing the task.

Answer (score 0):

From **Atom > Preferences > Install**:

Search for **atom-runner** package and install it.

Close the **atom** editor and reopen. This helps the atom editor set the right path and will solve the issue.

If this doesnt help, manually copy the folder of the python installation directory and add the path to system **PATH**. This will solve the issue.