# Running a Python file with atom

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using atom for 2 months to run Julia files and it works.

I would like to run some python files too

To do that, I installed the [IDE-python package](https://atom.io/packages/ide-python)

When Atom is started, there is the following picture:

[image]

I can run a Julia file without problem, but I can't run a python file (and there is not a python console...)

How can I add it and run the python file ?

Comment: Kind of off-topic comment- but why do you need to run python within atom? its trivial to execute a python program in a terminal window.

Comment: Because I have a big file and I would like to execute a Julia file and a Python file in the same IDE...

Comment: ok. I am not sure if it is still around but `script` might a package worth looking into for you

Comment: Try [atom-python-run package](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python from Atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585500/running-python-from-atom)

Comment: This package is installed yet and I read the precedent topic before open it. It is not working in my case ( I installed `Script` and I tried `CTRL + Shift + B`). So it is not what I found, because It is not possible to see my precedent codes in Python and the error of them... So I think I can do with this solution...

Answer (score 0):

You should load the Script module into Atom. Once loaded, it will show up under the packages menu or you can use the command-I keystroke to run your python code.

To use a shell to run python install the module platformio-ide-terminal. When you click this under packages you'll get an option to toggle a terminal window. It will show up in the bottom third of Atom window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed the PlatformIO IDE Terminal but I have still a problem: I read the [commands](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal#commands) of the PlatformIO IDE Terminal but when I tried to run my Python file (with Crtl + enter), it is not working: The cursor go to the next line...    If I run the program with the bottom on the left, the program is running it with Julia...

Comment: From the new terminal you should run your code with "python filename.py" and return.